# Will a QR-code in an Android Automotive app be approved?

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, automotive

We are currently developing an app for cars with Android Automotive.
There is a desire to include a QR-code in the application, so that the user can (while the car is *not* moving) scan the QR-code and be directed to the website to fill in a form via their phone. The developer guidelines does not say anything about QR-codes in the application. However, the section about visual design and user interaction includes guidelines regarding images, but they are somewhat difficult to interpret. Also, it is unsure whether they apply to the use of a QR-code. The question is whether a QR-code in an android app for cars will be approved.

I tried sending the question to Google support, but their answer was "Unfortunately I'm not able to comment on your planned implementation. If you think your app is in compliance, please submit your app for another review. You may want to review the Developer Program Policies for additional policy guidance", which I found quite annoying, since we want to know whether the use of a QR-code will be approved before we spend time on the implementation.

We have documentation and guidelines, but are unable to find the answer.

Thank you in advance for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotify and ABRP already use QR codes in AAOS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).